# Can i make console logs visible in a cordova app running on an emulator?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, quasar

Hello i'am currently building an app with cordova and the quasar framework.
I'm experiencing some problems in my android version running on an emulator that dont happen in my web version.
Is there a way to make the errors visible in some way or another.
Im using android studio as my emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Open a chrome window on the same machine the emulator is running on. Navigation to chrome://inspect/#devices, you should be able to debug the emulator from there, giving you the full devtools, providing the APK is a dev build. This will not work for production builds.